# How to use custom media type formatter for signalr message content?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to use custom media type formatters to implement (part of the) versioning for a Web API service. This works fine with standard Web API controller methods. The service also uses SignalR to notify connected clients of certain changes. Below the relevant code of the Hub:

```
    public void BroadCastAnalyzerGroupRemoved(string groupId)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.AnalyzerGroupRemoved(
            new AnalyzerGroupRemovedMessage() 
            { 
                AnalyzerGroupId = groupId 
            });
    }
```

Without use of custom media type formatters this worked fine. When removing all formatters from the HttpConfiguration and adding only my custom ones like below, the code above throws the following exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message='Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'AnalyzerGroupRemoved'
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=false
  Message='Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'AnalyzerGroupRemoved'
  Source=Microsoft.CSharp
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError)
  InnerException:
```

The code used to configure formatters looks like this:

```
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        var formatters = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter>>();
        formatters.ForEach(f => config.Formatters.Add(f));
```

Where the `container` object is an Autofac container that contains all the custom media type formatters.

I've verified that the media type formatter for the `AnalyzerGroupRemovedMessage` is created and added to the container.

Do I need to add some code to the registration at the client side?
The code to register currently looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task TestRemovingAGroupNotifiesClients()
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(uriBuilder.SignalRHubUri, useDefaultUrl: false);
        hubConnection.Error += ex => { throw new Exception("Exception from hubConnection",ex); };
        hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
        hubConnection.TraceWriter = new DebugTextWriter();
        var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("AnalyzerGroupsHub");
        const string groupId = "138"; 
        var eventWasRecieved = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        string groupIdRecieved = null;
        proxy.On<AnalyzerGroupRemovedMessage>("AnalyzerGroupRemoved", message =>
        {
            groupIdRecieved =  message.AnalyzerGroupId;
            eventWasRecieved.Set();
        });
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        var removeResult = await RequestHelper.InvokeWebRequest(
            uriBuilder.AnalyzerGroupUri(groupId),
            HttpMethod.Delete);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, removeResult.StatusCode);
        var waitResult = eventWasRecieved.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Assert.IsTrue(waitResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(groupId, groupIdRecieved);
    }
```

I was unable to find any information on the internet regarding this topic, any pointers to resources would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Simple answer, you don't. You're mixing 2 differnet frameworks. SignalR is JSON and JSON alone.

Comment: @dfowler, can you elaborate on that, the custom media type used here is also JSON. I would expect SignalR to participate in content negotiation, which should make the above feasible. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, SignalR knows nothing about media type formatters or content negotiation (it's not a REST framework). Those types are specific to HttpClient and WebAPI. SignalR is neither of those.